# Referencing WhatID in tasks?

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, update, whatid

I have a lookup on Teams called `Managers` (User Lookup).

When a task related to Teams is completed, I want to update a field on tasks  called `match` and

also update a field on Teams called `completed = true` if the `Assigned to on the task == the manager on teams`.

I’m stuck since Im not exactly sure how to match tasks `assigned to== manager field`.

Should I set a variable to = my manager Id then query out a list of tasks to see if the assigned to field matches that variable? Then how would I include it in my IF statement?

And how do I update task and team? This will only update teams? I think I need to query tasks where the whatId ==teams as well?

I don’t think I should actually reference Team__c but the whatIds for tasks? Ive never written anything with tasks so I have no idea how the relationships work or how it should. I think I need to scratch everything and start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you need to divide your code into two parts(Assuming you have a trigger on Task object):

**Before Update trigger part**:

Here you will grab all the tasks which are

1. Related to Teams and whose
2. status changed to complete

Then Update `Match` field of task.

**Note:** Before triggers are generally used to set the fields of same object.

**After Update Trigger part**

Here again you will grab tasks which are

1. Related to Teams and whose
2. status changed to complete and
3. assignedToId == Team.managerId

Then you will make a list of all these teams, and update `Completed` field of team.

**Note:** After triggers are generally used to set the fields of other object or to create or update records of other objects.

There is a [Trigger module on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro) which you can see also following link contain some patterns to write triggers.

[Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)

Comment: I have updated my answer with some useful links which i think you should look. Then please update your code with the changes you have made and specify exactly what issue you are facing. It is really simple that's why i am not writing entire trigger for you.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be more or less like this

```
    public static void checkIfTaskCompleted (Map<Id, Task> newTasks, Map<Id, Task> oldTasks){
    List<Team__c> teamsTobeUpdated = new List<Team__c>();
    Set<Id> teamIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> managerIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Id> teamToAssignToMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Task t : newTasks.values()){
        // collect all the tasks whose status is changed to completed
        if(t.Status != oldTasks.get(t.Id).Status && t.status == 'Completed'){
            // collect all the team ids whose tasks are modified
            teamIds.add(t.whatId);
            // collect all the task's assigned tos to query on teams
            managerIds.add(t.ownerId);
            // collect team id to assigned to mapping to be used for later processing
            teamToAssignToMap.put(t.whatId, t.ownerId);
        }
    }
    // query for teams whose tasks are modified and manager is on one of the task's assigned to
    Map<Id, Team__c> teamMap = new Map<Id, Team__c>([SELECT Id, Manager__c FROM Team__c WHERE Id IN :teamIds AND Manager__c IN :managerIds LIMIT 50000]);
    for(Task t : newTasks.values()){
        // verify that task assigned to is same as manager on the team
        if(teamMap.containsKey(t.whatId) && t.ownerId == teamMap.get(t.whatId).Manager__c){
            // you don't need to exclusively update tasks as you are modifying the values in newer version of the records
            t.match__c = true;
            Team__c team = new Team__c(Id = t.whatId, Completed__c = true);
            teamsTobeUpdated.add(team);
        }
    }
    // you can do this or database.update as per your desire
    update teamsTobeUpdated;
}
```

Comment: You mean manager field is looking up Account instead of User?